# How to remove Â from the inner text of an Element

Tags: jquery, html

When i tried to extract the inner Text of the below  element using jQuery text() method,

```
<a href="http://www.abcxyz.com">This is the Link. Learn more.</a>
```

am getting the below string as the output.

Output String: `This is the Link.Â Learn more.`

I don't want "Â" in the output string. How can i replace it?

Comment: You shouldn't replace it, you should fix your character encoding so it doesn't appear.

Comment: This is a character encoding issue.

Comment: @adeneo. I will not be able to change the <a> element as i don't have access/permission to do that. But, i need to extract the text without that "Â". Is there any other ways to do it?

Comment: How are you extracting the text? You obviously messed up somewhere, saved a file in a different encoding etc. Everything should be UTF8, and the problem will solve itself.

Comment: @adeneo as i mentioned earlier, i don't have permission to edit the file and also am using tag manager with asynchronous way to extract the text from the page element using jQuery's text() method.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
string s = "This is the Link.Â Learn more.";
string newString = s.Replace("Â", "");
```